# Extract and sort numbers from filnames in python

Tags: python, numbers, extract

I have a very basic question. I have files named like `Dipole_E0=1.2625E-01.dat` and I want to extract the `1.2625E-01` part and finally sort them by ascending order. How can this be done ? I tried first to plit the filename with .split() but it does not what I expect. Thanks for your help.

Best

Roland

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to use regexp. To obtain value from file name:

```
m = re.search(filename, '^Dipole_E0=(.*)/s?')
val = m.group(0)
```

Walk through all dilenames and append all values to array. After that sort and that's all.

Comment: Ok I'll check that. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look into regular expressions. In python they live in the re module. Depending on exact format, something like:

```
import re
ematch = re.compile("=([0-9]*\.[0-9]*[eE][+-][0-9]+)")
val = ematch.search(filename).group(0)
```

Sorting a  list can be done with the .sort() method on lists, or the sorted(list) builtin, which give you a new list.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the filenames with the glob module.

```
    from glob import glob
    file_names = glob("yourpath/*.dat")

    vals = []
    for name in file_names:
         vals.append(float(name[:-4].rpartition("=")[2]))

    vals.sort()
```

name[:-4] throws away the ".dat". rpartition is a string method. It returns a tuple where entry 0 is the string left of the string used to split, entry 1 is the string used to split (here: "=") and entry 2 is the string right of this string (here: your float). Then it is converted to a float and appended to the list of values.

Comment: Right, seems what I needed for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a good situation to use a [generator expression](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t85uBptTDYY) and [the `sorted` builtin](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
sorted(float(filename.split("=", 1)[1].rsplit(".", 1)[0]) for filename in filenames)
```

Where `filenames` is your list of filenames.

```
>>> filenames = ["Dipole_E0=1.2625E-01.dat", "Dipole_E0=1.3625E-01.dat", "Dipole_E0=0.2625E-01.dat"]
>>> sorted(float(filename.split("=", 1)[1].rsplit(".", 1)[0]) for filename in filenames)
[0.02625, 0.12625, 0.13625]
```

Comment: Good. I needed the part where you transform the extracted string into a float. Thanks.